# .Net and Mono sharing different version of the same assembly in a solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono, ninject, nuget

I am using Ninject IoC assembly - an external assembly for IoC , they support both mono and windows. but to work on mono a different compiled version of the assembly is needed.

I have the following problem:

I have a Domain.Core project that uses Ninject windows version
I have two additional project - Call them For.Mono and For.Windows, they both have reference for the Domain.Core project

The problem is that For Ninject to work on mono we have to compile it with a special compilation symbol.

Now the mono version will not work on windows, how can I have resolve the issue of using both versions in the same solution to have the following:

When I run the For.Mono project only the Mono version of Ninject is used, even if the Domain.Core project is using Ninject in some classes inside it's code and referencing the local to it's score windows version - I would like to override this with the Mono version somehow,

And use the Ninject windows version on the For.Windows project, this issue is trivial as it just works, but the first request I am asked to reference the windows version by the compiler when I use code from the Domain.Core in my For.Mono project. I understand that the compiler is right but how can I resolve this issue of cross-platform support with one code-base

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not exactly clear, but from what I gather: You have shared base classes/interfaces in `Domain.Core` assembly that your project uses, you also have 2 sets of derived classes/interfaces (`For.Windows` and `For.Mono`) that provide platform specific implementation of classes/interfaces from `Domain.Core`. You want to have both `For.XXX` referenced from your solution.

I don't see problem with that approach. As long as your code only refers to classes from `Domain.Core` and instantiation code is wrapped in

```
if (platform = Platform1) 
{
    // must be function calls in both branches to avoid JIT-ing references 
    // to unsupporterd DLL for the other platform.
    InstantiatePlatformOneClasses();
}
else
    InstantiatePlatformTwoClasses();
```

there should be no problem at either compile or run-time.

Note: using some DI container will solve the same issues easier since you can simply configure it to pick platform specific implementations a run-time.

Comment: I don't want to have code that uses if, I want the app to compile cross platform, without ifs, to stick to DRY

Comment: @DavidMZ - If you want cross platform support then only use Mono.  There is no reason your application when compiled against the Mono Framework cannot work on Windows.